# How to obtain the name of an active Excel spreadsheet and pass it into Java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am working on a Java app that I need to integrate with Excel.

When testing the Java app, I can hard code the excel workbook name and can do everything that I need to.

But, the intention is to have an excel workbook open and run a vb macro that launches the Java code and populates the FileInputStream name with the active workbook name, not hard code the workbook name in.

What I need to do is either:

In Java, somehow get the name and path of the current active excel workbook as a text string and use that in my code in place of the hard coded name, as the intention is to have it run on various workbooks.

I was unable to find a way of doing that via Apache POI.

There only seems to be a getSheetName method available?

Or alternatively, I can probably get vb to get the name of the current workbook as a string, but I'm unsure how I would pass that string into Java to use as the workbook name string variable.

That's the only sticking point, everything else in the java code runs as I would like it to.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you want the active worksheet, there is a `getActiveSheetIndex()` method in the `Workbook` class, so you might be able to combine that with `getSheetName()`

```
String worksheetName = workbook.getSheetName(workbook.getActiveSheetIndex());
```

Unless you want the actual path to the workbook (xls) open in Excel that is calling the java program, then you'd likely want to pass in the name of the workbook file as a parameter to your java executable.

Ex. in VB:
`Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` will get you the active workbook path.

My VB is a bit rusty but I think it'll be something like:

```
Call Shell("java YourJavaProgram" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path)
```

And you can refer to user506069's answer for getting arguments on the Java side.

Answer (score 1):

If your VB macro is truly going to be launching the Java program then you can specify the workbook name as a command-line argument. It will be passed into the main method of your Java program using its String[] parameter.

Please see this document for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String workbookName = args[0];
    //continue executing business code from here
}
```